# Unique constraint for combined columns queried with another column

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, constraints

Add table constraint for combined columns

I have a database table with below columns to store contact details

```
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `id` int(11),
  `user_id` int(11), -- Foreign key to user table
  `contact_type` enum('Email', 'Phone', 'Address') -- Possible values
  `contact` varchar(100),
  `is_verified` tinyint(1),  -- Boolean
  `is_primary` tinyint(1), -- Boolean
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Is it possible to set a constraint on `is_primary` column so that one user can have maximum one primary contact on each `contact_type` ?

Comment: which database are  you using oracle or postgresql or mysql?

Comment: At the moment I am using Postgres, But any answer is welcome

Comment: Then remove the backtics. They are an error in any SQL implementation except mysql. And Postgres has a Boolean datatype, so you don't need the tinyint stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a unique constraint/index to do this:

```
create unique index unq_contacts_user_id_contact_type_is_primary
    on contact(user_id, contact_type, is_primary);
```

Note:  this only works if `is_primary` takes on the values "1" or `NULL`.  This is very important.  Otherwise, you will be limited to at most one "not primary" contact as well as one primary one.

In Postgres (or Oracle), you would use a filtered index:

```
create unique index unqf_contacts_user_id_contact_type
    on contact(user_id, contact_type)
    where is_primary = 1; -- or however you specify that it is true
```